# neo4j Use a relationship to find related property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relationship like:
    (U:User)-[r:tagged{tagID,timestamp}]->(P:Player{Name='Tom'})

```
User1 tagged player Tom,the tagID is 1 and the tagName is good
User2 tagged player Tom,the tagID is 2 and the tagName is bad
```

and nodes like:
    (t:tag{tagID,tagName})

```
tagID  tagName
1      Good
2      Bad
```

nodes 'tag' and relationship tagged are using the same tagID,how can I find all tagName such as Good,Bad etc. based on a given player name such as Tom? I try something like below :

```
match (:User)-[r:tagged]->(P:Player{Name:'Tom'}),(t:tag)
where t.tagID=r.tagID
return t.tagName
order by tagName desc
limit 20
```

and I get syntax error.
what I expect is

```
tagName
Good
Bad
```

Comment: Still not very clear. You speak about Users in your description, but they are not part of your question. Also, what have you tried and what did you get instead of what you were expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit, your query looks almost right, just needs a few minor adjustments.

You should probably add your syntax error, but I would guess it's because you're trying to order on just "tagName", which isn't a variable or column in scope ("t.tagName" is in scope, you may want to alias it)

You'll also want to make sure you use distinct in there somewhere, either on the tagID on after on the matched tags, as it's possible for multiple people to have tagged the player with the same tag.

Try this:

```
match (:User)-[r:tagged]->(:Player{Name:'Tom'})
with distinct r.tagID as tagID
match (t:tag)
where t.tagID = tagID
return t.tagName AS tagName
order by tagName desc
limit 20
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question without more information. 
1. In your relationship description there is no `property3`.
2. You haven't included an real information about your objects or their relationships.

My guess though is you want something like this:
`match(b {property0:'VALUE0'}) match(b)<-[r:{property1:'VALUE1', property2:'VALUE2'}]-(a) return a`

This basically says, create a variable b and assign it the objects in the db that have property0 with value equal to VALUE. Then create another variable a and assign it the values that have a relationship with b where the relationship has property1 equal to VALUE1 and property2 equal to VALUE2.
Please include more details about what you are trying to accomplish and what errors you are receiving if this isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: More details are added,sorry for the previous question.